# ¿"Qué va a hacer" es una muletilla?[Tal como "Qué sé yo"]

Tags: expresiones, significado, modismos, argentina

- Así que bueno, qué sé yo, que va a hacer.

¿«Qué va a hacer» es una muletilla tal como «Qué sé yo»?

«Va a ser» es la perífrasis verbal «ir a» seguida del verbo «hacer».

- ¡Qué+va a+hacer!

No es «Qué va a ser» ¿cierto? Porque suena como «qué va'ser»/«qué va'cer», aunque a veces no es exclamativo o interrogativo, sino que más bien un comentario al aire o para sí mismo, o una frase después de una larga argumentación como tratando de convencer o convencerse, de llegar a un consenso, o estar hablando de algo de lo cual no depende de quienes hablan encontrar una solución o que a pesar de lo hablado no se llega una conclusión, similar a:

EDIT2:

- ¡En fin!
- ¡Es lo que es!
- ¡Me conformo a pesar de todo!
- ¡Ni hablar!
- ¡No hay nada que hacer!
- ¡Será nomás!
- ¡No hay por donde!
- ¡Lo que sea!
- ¡Más no te puedo decir!
- ¡Es lo que hay!
- ¡Es lo que tenemos!
- ¡Ya está, qué va a hacer!
- ¡Ni modo!
- ¡No hay manera!
- ¡De ninguna manera!
- ¡Qué+va a+ser!

Sin embargo he leído cosas como:

- ¿Qué va ser? (pero incredulidad sobre un hecho en su lugar)

Lo conozco como:

- Qué se le va a hacer.

o

- Qué le vamos a hacer(integrando a la(s) otra(s) persona(s))

Se lo he escuchado a argentinos cuando hay un silencio en la conversación simplemente como una especie de muletilla que no viene al caso, creo que de Rosario, pero también de otras regiones. También en imitaciones de Carlos Salvador Bilardo p.ej. o en muchas entrevistas.

También he leído que tiene el significado de "no lo puedo creer" en Perú y en algunos países de Centroamérica.

EDIT: Quiero agregar que también he escuchado: ¡Ya está! como el that's it! seguido de eso. "¡Que (se le) va a hacer!" indica a veces resignación" o conformidad(la suma de todo eso, es resultado final, la situación en la que se está luego de decir una retahíla de cosas negativas para las cuales no hay nada que hacer) ¡Ni modo! se lo he escuchado a los mexicanos en su lugar y creo que también a los argentinos.

Comment: La lógica dicta que ha de ser "*qué va a ser*" (=[yo no sé] qué será). "*Qué va a hacer*" no tiene sentido. ¿Quién va a hacer qué? (*Qué le vamos a hacer* es una pregunta aparte.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pregunta, debería haberse dicho:

- «Va a ser» es la perífrasis verbal «ir a» seguida del verbo «**ser**».

pero no lo quise corregir porque implicaría una modificación del razonamiento seguido por OP.

Entiendo el comentario de nopaltepec, pero considerando el significado y uso de la muletilla, al menos en Argentina, me inclino a pensar que es un apócope de (1):

1. ¿Qué se le va a hacer?

Así, de (1) derivan los aparentemente incorrectos pero muy usados:

2. ¿Qué (se) le va a hacer?
3. ¿Qué (se le) va a hacer?

(1), (2) y (3) usados como muletillas significan "no hay nada para hacer" y suenan más impersonales que "¿qué le vamos a hacer?"

Para mí, la muletilla es una pregunta retórica, de ahí que la interrogación no es muy fuerte.

Comment: Excelente, quiero agregar que también he escuchado: ¡Ya está! como el that's it! seguido de eso. "¡Que (se le) va a hacer!" indica a veces "resignación"(la suma de todo eso, luego de decir una retahíla de cosas negativas para las cuales no hay nada que hacer) ¡Ni modo! se lo he escuchado a los mexicanos en su lugar.